# Post amount must be in increments of 50 PHP

Tags: php

i collect data using GET.

```
product=shoes&amount=30
```

so i collect the data

```
$amount = $_GET['amount'];
```

How do i echo out a message if the amount is not in increments of 10, so for example if amount was 25, i want to echo out saying "Amount needs to be in increments of 10".
I have no code examples as i have tried to google this and can't find anything and i don't know where to even begin.

So i have not tried anything.

Comment: but you definitely should try something

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

Comment: Duplicate easily found via “php check if number is multiple of another” ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$amount = $_GET['amount'];
if($amount%10!=0){
    echo "Amount needs to be in increments of 10";
}
```